# Instantiate Class and Call Class Method in one step

Tags: vb.net, class, methods, instantiation, simultaneous

Anyone know of a way to instantiate (`Dim`) a class ***and*** call a method on that class in one step (no the method **can't** be `Shared`)?

I'm thinking something like `Call (New SecG(oDBConn)).fCallAudit()`

Comment: `a way to instantiate (Dim) ` `Dim` does not instantiate an object.  It *declares* a variable of some Type.

Comment: @Plutonix, I was referring tersely to (`Dim someVar As someType = New someType()`); however, you're correct.  `Dim` doesn't instantiate a new variable; `New` does.

Answer (score 1):

NEVER MIND, this ***actually*** works (the VS IntelliSense was slow and needed to rebuild to show that this doesn't create a compile-error).

To instantiate & call in one line:

`Call (New SecG(oDBConn)).fCallAudit()`